# Patient probability of showing up

Tags: model

I have patient visit data which includes:

- appointment date,
- clinic,
- appointment type (new or a review appointment),
- appointment priority (urgent, not urgent),
- age,
- gender,
- site,
- attendance status (showed up, did not show up).

Given that the patient can attend multiple sites – multiple clinics – and the patient visits can happen at different intervals.

If I would like to include the historical attendance of the patient, what will be the best model to predict patient attendance?